# How to append checkbox value to specific category it belongs

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have some check-boxes with values that belong to different categories (e.g. movies, music, books etc.). When the user checks the check-box the value gets appended but I also want the category name to be appended too, but only for the first time.

Example :

1. The user checks "Mad Max" under the movies category.
2. The `<li>` with checkbox value get's appended and also "Movies" gets appended on top of it.
3. The user checks "Back to the Future", this time the category name should not get appended because it is already there.

Also, if the user unchecks the check-box I would like the value to be erased and if it is the last value left, then the category name also will be removed.

I have tried several ways, but the biggest problem is dealing with the category name.

This is what I've got so far..

```
(function() {


    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {

        // Get value of an checkbox
        var value = $(this).parent('label').text();

        // Get value of Category name
        var categoryName = $(this).parents('.modal-body').siblings('.modal-header').children('.modal-title').text();

        //Where to append items
        var list = $('#checkbox-list');

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            $('<span class="item-filter" />' + '<br>').prependTo(list).html('<a href="#" id="delete-filter">X</a>' + value);

            $('<span class="category-title" />' + '<br>').prependTo(list).text(categoryName);

        } else {
            $('#checkbox-list span:contains(' + value + ')').remove();
        }

        //Show Reset and Save buttons 

        $('.filterButton').css('display', 'inline-block');


        // Close button (vissualy delete filter and uncheck specific checkbox)

        $('#filter-sidebar').on('click', '#delete-filter', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var item = $(this).parents('.item-filter');
            item.remove();

            //reset specific checkbox
            $('label:contains(' + itemValue + ')').closest('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);

        })
    }); 

    // Reset Button 

    $('#resetFilters').on('click', function(){

        //visually empty the list
        $('#checkbox-list').slideUp().empty();
        $('.filterButton').css('display', 'none');

        //reset all checkboxes 
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    });


})();
```

Comment: Show us your code please. Show us what you have tried or better yet, create a demo illustrating the issue on http://plnkr.co/

Comment: I edited question and added code example. I will also set up demo litlle bit later.

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML too please.

Comment: Check-boxes are added dynamically, and they are displayed in bootstrap modal dialog, so i am not sure adding that HTML would help..
Do you have any advice how would you solve the Category name problem ? I do not need for 100% solution, just some advice to get me started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'm not at all sure this is what you are after as your post wasn't that clear, but hopefully it will give you some idea of how you could go about this.

Here's a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/bZmkoVhAGy8nkh00sq1i?p=preview).

One of the key points to note is the use of `.data()` function to access custom data attributes that you add to your HTML elements. I have used them in the code below to add category values to each checkbox.

So in your HTML we have:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Mad Max" data-category="Movies">
```

And we can access this in jQuery like so:

`$checkedBox.data('category') // "Movies"`

I have tried to explain as much as I can in the comments. Hope this helps.

**script.js**

```
// shorthand for $(document).ready(handler)
$(function() {

    var $groupContainers  = $('.group-containers'),

        // out 'model': a list of objects representing user choices
        userChoices       = [];

    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {

        var $checkedBox     = $(this),
            checkedBoxLabel = $checkedBox.parent('label').text(),
            checkedValue    = $checkedBox.val(), 
            category        = $checkedBox.data('category'),
            alreadyChecked  = !$checkedBox[0].checked;


        if(alreadyChecked){
          removeChoiceFromModel(category, checkedValue);
        } else {
          addChoiceToModel(category, checkedValue);
        }

        updateDom();

        return;
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function cleanGroupContainers(){
          $groupContainers.each(function(){
              var list = $(this).find('ul');

              if(list.length){
                list.remove();
              }
          });
        }


        function updateDom(){

          // reset dom - not efficient but easier to
          // keep list state in sync
          cleanGroupContainers();
          appendChoices();
          hideEmptyLists();
        }

      function appendChoices(){

         var i, option, $categoryDiv,

            len = userChoices.length;

        // if len === 0 then no need to check
        if(!len) return false;

        for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
          option        = userChoices[i];
          $categoryDiv  = $('#' + option.category + '-container');

          $categoryDiv.append('<ul><li>'+option.value+'</li></ul>'); 
        }

      }

      function hideEmptyLists(){

        $groupContainers.each(function(){
            var $container = $(this),
                items = $container.find('ul > li');

            if(!items.length){
              $container.hide();
              // skip to next iteration
              return true;
            }

            $container.show();
        });
      }

      function addChoiceToModel(category, value){
        userChoices.push({
          category: category,
          value: checkedValue
        });
      }

      function removeChoiceFromModel(category, value){

        var i, option,

            len = userChoices.length;

        // if len === 0 then no need to check
        if(!len) return false;

        for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
          option = userChoices[i];

          if(option.category === category && option.value === value){
            // remove choice object from array
            userChoices.splice(i, 1);
            return;
          }
        }

      }

    }); 

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div>
      <h4>Movies</h4>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="Mad Max" data-category="Movies"> Mad Maxx</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="Pulp Fiction" data-category="Movies"> Pulp Fiction</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4>Music</h4>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="Justin Bieber" data-category="Music"> Justin Bieber</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="One Direction" data-category="Music"> One Direction</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4>Books</h4>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="Dracular" data-category="Books"> Dracular</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="Trainspotting" data-category="Books"> Trainspotting</label>
    </div>


    <div id="checkbox-list">
      <div id="Movies-container" class="group-containers">
        <h3>Movies</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="Music-container" class="group-containers">
        <h3>Music</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="Books-container" class="group-containers">
        <h3>Books</h3>
      </div>

    </div>




  </body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.group-containers{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Matt, thank you for taking the time to write this ! This is really helpful.